# A code before the display of each page

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I want to run a code on each page of my website, before the page is displayed.
In webforms i used to place this code in the page_load of the master page.
But Where could i do it in MVC?

Comment: What code do you intend to place in this method? Maybe there's more MVCish way to achieve what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always create a base class for your controllers, override the OnActionExecuting method and put the code you need to run there.

Example

```
public class HomeController : BaseController
{
}

public class BaseController : Controller
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        // do stuff here
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```